# Html5 section or not to section?

Tags: html

I'm learning about HTML5, and honestly I can't say I'm really impressed. Semantics are nice and all, but I think that they introduced new elements with a very thin line between them, and a even thinner line between them and the *old divs*.

Everything is very clear if you do a *generic purpose* site, like a blogging engine, news publishing portal, and similar, but web apps... I'm having a lot of dilemmas about new html elements.

Here is my situation. I'm developing an ordering system. On the sellers interface I have 3 columns (inline), which represent the status of the order. When the status is changed element is moved from one column into another (background ajax, and js manipulation).

In Html4 I would use 3 divs and put a heading with a title on top of each one. Elements inside the columns would also be *divs*.

But what about HTML5? I have been looking at the *section* element, but I'm not really sure how to use it. Here are the options:

1. Put everything inside one *section* - I don't think that is the way to go
2. Put a *section* around each of the column *divs*, and heading inside the *section*
3. Replace the *divs* with *sections*
4. Put *sections* inside column *divs*

So, which way to go?

**EDIT:** first of all thanks everyone for your quick replies. In the end I'll probably go with Ian Devlins suggestion, and put each column as *section*. Anyway, just to point out my dissatisfaction with html5, multiple permitted options aren't always a good thing. I'm afraid what will the html5 web look like in a few years, when we can't fully agree on a simple question like this.

**EDIT2:** one more thing. I'll ask it here so I don't have to open another question. In addition to these 3 columns I have another *div* which contains order details, when any of the orders are selected. Should it be an *article* since its *self-contained content*, or to use an *aside* tag?

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is an excellent question.

Comment: Boo you're evil and mean! You should accept it anyway and then comment on your reservations about it? Regarding your order details, an article makes more sense here rather than an aside, as the content is more than relevant to the page. That said, a div might make more sense.

Comment: first, you really should start marking more answers as accepted. I very much doubt that out of the 18 questions asked, only 7 had decent answers. Second, if you really aren't sure "this is the way to go" then you really need to re-read my answer because it seems like you are still lacking an understanding for the what, why, and when of HTLM5 tags.

Comment: Ok ok, here is your accepted mark. Id just like to point out that if I don't accept an answer, that doesn't mean that any of the answers aren't decent, just that they do not answer the specific question correctly. Hints and tips are fine, but I can't accept them as answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case I would have an overall div around them, and then each column as a section as each one has a different meaning, each of which I assume has a heading indicating its status.

e.g.

```
<div>
   <section id="col1">
      <header><h1>Column 1</h1></header>
      content....
   </section>
   <section id="col2">
      <header><h1>Column 2</h1></header>
      content....
   </section>
   <section id="col3">
      <header><h1>Column 3</h1></header>
      content....
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why a *header* inside each *section*? Aren't the *h1* tags enough since there is always only one *h1* per section

Comment: Yes, you could do that, I just chose to add the header.

Answer (score 5):

`div` is a perfectly valid HTML5 tag. If the new tags don't make any sense in your project, don't feel forced to use them.

Comment: I know. But everything from HTML4 is valid in HTML5, so if I stick with that philosophy I wouldn't use it at all. But I can't make out if the new elements are supposed to replace the divs, or to wrap around/inside them

Comment: In your case, I'm guessing your 3 columns (`div`s) are probably already wrapped in a `div` which we could call *order status section*; in this case, you could use the new `section` tag. But the inner `div`s, are no `section`, `article`, `footer`, etc. so they might as well remain plain old `div`s.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the w3.org spec:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.

And another quote from the w3.org people:

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

Given the definition for `section` by w3 we can conclude that your example would be a good use of section because:

1. The elements have a header
2. It is a thematic grouping of content
3. It is a part of the document outline.

**EDIT:**
To expand upon your comment below, the new HTML5 elements are **NOT** supposed to replace the old HTML4 elements. For example, going through a page and replacing all the `div` elements with `section` elements would be flat out wrong. The `section` element was, in my opinion, intended to make it easier for machines to parse certain pages (think: feedburners) by giving a more semantic structure to a page. After all, what's easier to parse, a page with 30 `div` elements, or a page with 10 `div` 5 `header` 5 `section` 5 `article` and 5 `footer` elements?

Comment: Thanks. But can you define *thematic grouping of content*? Isn't a column with elements with the same status considered a *thematic group*?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part of your question that was key. Your example could actually use the section tag.

Comment: Ok. But can you be a little more specific? *Section* for each columns like @Ian Devlin suggested, or an overlay *section* like @madd0 suggested

Comment: I would personally style it as @Ian suggested; it is semantically correct and easy to understand the code at a glance.